# Call a function from a functional component React Native

Tags: react-native, function, react-functional-component

I have the next problem, trying to call a function from a functional component, like `shared` in class components.
My test code is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const TestShared = () => {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)

    const increase = () => {
        return setNumber(prevValue => prevValue + 1)
    }

    const getNumber = () => {
        return number
    }
}
```

In another file I import `TestShared` and trying to call the functions like `TestShared.increase()` or `TestShared.getNumber()` but of course is undefined.

How can I achieve this without using `useContext`? If there is any possible way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can check code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-colden-qj4h8?file=/src/App.js)

```
const TestShared = () => {
 const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)

    const increase = () => {
        return setNumber(prevValue => prevValue + 1)
    }

    const getNumber = () => {
        return number
    }

    return {
        increase,
        getNumber
    };
}

export default TestShared ;
```

And where you want this function just import like this

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

import TestShared from './Helpers/TestShared' 

function MyComponent = () => {
    const {increase, getNumber} = TestShared();
}
```

Comment: I get ``getNumber`` is not exported from ``TestShared``.

Comment: Looks good at first sight but after testing it it throws an error:
`TypeError: (0, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[7], "./Helpers/TestShared").increase) is not a function. (In '(0, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[7], "./Helpers/TestShared").increase)()', '(0, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[7], "./Helpers/TestShared").increase)' is undefined)` <- I've left it here if it might help you

Comment: can you please share code where you are import this code

Comment: @arslan --- this is how i import them : `import { increase, getNumber } from './Helpers/TestShared'` and this is how i call them:  ` <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>  increase() }>` and `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => getNumber()}>`

Comment: But i imported them the same way as you, just the path is different because the `TestShared` file is in a different folder than the file that calls it

Comment: did you try this one which I told you?
Because you didn't export separately you just return this function so you can't import this function directly you need to destructre

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231402/discussion-between-popatheguru-and-arslan).

Comment: no you are wrong import like this **import TestShared from "./Helpers/TestShared"; ** and then where you want this function mean where you use state and other stuff there import this const {increase, getNumber} = TestShared – arslan 16 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to expand a bit more on @arsian's answer after some experimentation.

1. The names used when importing the objects in the parent component MUST match the exact same names of the exported elements in the child component, other way, the returning will be undefined:

Child component:

```
return {
        increase,
        getNumber
    };
export default TestShared ;
```

Parent component:

```
const {wrongName, getWrong} = TestShared(); //This will NOT work
console.log(wrongName); //undefined

const {increse, getNumber} = TestShared(); //This WILL work
```

2. The returning elements can be the `state` and the `setState` function, actually, they can be of any type(function,array,object,list...). Also, the order of the elements when exporting or importing does not matter (the name does). For example,

Child component:

```
const arr = [0];
const obj = { a: 1 };
function fn() {
        console.log(arr, obj);
  };

return {
        number,
        setNumber,
        arr,
        obj,
        fn

    };
```

Parent component:

```
const {number, setNumber,obj,arr,fn} = TestShared();
console.log(arr,obj);
fn();

// [0],{a:1}
```

While the last point could be very intuitive, the first point gave me some troubles since I was thinking the order of the elements was the important factor and not the names. Because of that, I wanted to share my experimenting about sharing state between components in `React`.

Cheers.

Comment: Pretty interesting observation, also I thought it's all about the order, not the names. Thank you for this info